# Convenient Terminal GNOME Extension which hides and unhides when key is pressed

Tags: command-line, gnome, software-recommendation, shortcut-keys, gnome-shell-extension

Ideally I would like a way of easily toggling it so that a Terminal window (or something of the sort) appears over the top of everything when I press a certain keyboard shortcut and then disappears again when the keyboard shortcut is pressed again (or another keyboard shortcut), but I would like it so that it stays on top of everything while another window is selected. Is there a way to get something like this? Preferably it would be a GNOME Shell extension. I am running Ubuntu GNOME 15.10 with GNOME 3.18.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The GNOME Shell extension [Drop Down Terminal](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/442/drop-down-terminal/) is just what you were looking for! Follow [these instructions](https://askubuntu.com/a/757326/364819) in order to install it.

By pressing the <kbd>`</kbd> key (the one above <kbd>TAB</kbd> on most keyboards) you will get a Terminal, press it again and the Terminal will be gone (if you wish to change the keyboard shortcut for it simply go `gnome-tweak-tool` --> `Extensions`, press the options button for the Extension and you should find the settings in there).

**Screencast (sorry about the bad video quality):**

[image: Drop Down Terminal GNOME Shell Extension Screencast]